# Agrupar dados de um Array PHP

Tags: php, array

Estou querendo agrupar o dados com o mesmo código deste array, já tentei diversas maneiras, mas até agora nada.
Alguém tem uma ideia?

```
array (size=5)
      0 => 
        array (size=2)
          'CODIGO' => string '231' (length=3)
          'NOME' => string 'Mary' (length=22)
      1 => 
        array (size=2)
          'CODIGO' => string '188' (length=3)
          'NOME' => string 'Bernardino' (length=16)
      2 => 
        array (size=2)
          'CODIGO' => string '188' (length=3)
          'NOME' => string 'Carlos' (length=19)
      3 => 
        array (size=2)
          'CODIGO' => string '93' (length=2)
          'NOME' => string 'Alessandra' (length=17)
      4 => 
        array (size=2)
          'CODIGO' => string '93' (length=2)
          'NOME' => string 'Aparecida' (length=9)
      5 => 
        array (size=2)
          'CODIGO' => string '93' (length=2)
          'NOME' => string 'Raquel' (length=12)
```

Desde já, obrigado!

Comment: Sua pergunta não está muito clara. Que dados você quer agrupar? Aqui tem umas dicas de como fazer uma pergunta um pouco mais completa, para aumentar a chance de uma resposta que ajude: [Ask] e [Help]. Depois, você pode [edit] a postagem e acrescentar detalhes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui dessa forma, meu array está em $recordCustomers.

```
$temp = array();

    foreach($recordCustomers as $arg)
    {
        $temp[$arg['CODIGO']][] = $arg['NOME'];
    }

    $output = array();

    foreach($temp as $id => $name)
    {
        $output[] = array(
                'CODIGO' => $id,
                'NOME' => $name
        );
    }


    var_dump($output);
```

Answer (score 1):

Você quer gerar uma array dientica a essa no  php ?
tente isso

```
<?php

$arr = array(
        array('CODIGO'=>'231','NOME'=>'Mary'),
        array('CODIGO'=>'188','NOME'=>'Bernardino'),
        array('CODIGO'=>'188','NOME'=>'Carlos'),
        array('CODIGO'=>'93','NOME'=>'Alessandra'),
        array('CODIGO'=>'93','NOME'=>'Aparecida'),
        array('CODIGO'=>'93','NOME'=>'Raquel')
      );
 print_r($arr);
?>
```

Comment: Não seria `'NOME' => 'Aparecida'` por exemplo?

Comment: @Ivcs atualizei obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Algo assim?

```
$dados[] = array('CODIGO' => 231, 'NOME' => 'Mary');
$dados[] = array('CODIGO' => 188, 'NOME' => 'Bernardino');
$dados[] = array('CODIGO' => 188, 'NOME' => 'Carlos');
$dados[] = array('CODIGO' => 93, 'NOME' => 'Alessandra');
$dados[] = array('CODIGO' => 93, 'NOME' => 'Aparecida');
$dados[] = array('CODIGO' => 93, 'NOME' => 'Raquel');

$dadosAgrupados = array();
foreach ($dados as $dado) {
    $dadosAgrupados[$dado['CODIGO']][] = $dado['NOME'];
}
```